Condition for dense isolated types
I need some help with proving the following:
Theorem. Let $T$ be a complete theory in a countable language and let $M \models T$.
If $|\mathcal{S}_n^\mathcal{M}| < 2^{\aleph_0}$ then the isolated types in $\mathcal{S}_n^\mathcal{M}$ are dense.
I tried reading the proof from Marker's book but there is a detail I am having trouble with. They do the following:
First, they state that if $[\varphi] \neq \varnothing$ and $[\varphi]$ do not contain any isolated types, then there exists a formula $\psi$ such that $[\varphi \land \psi], [\varphi \land \neg \psi] \neq \varnothing$ $(\star)$.
Then they assume that the types in $\mathcal{S}_n^\mathcal{M}$ are not dense i.e. there exists a formula $\varphi$ such that $[\varphi]$ contains no isolated types.
After that, they inductively build a tree with root $\varphi$ by applying $(\star)$. This tree has some good properties:

If $\psi, \chi$ are different formulas on the same level, then $\psi \models \neg \chi$.
If $\psi$ is an ancestor of $\chi$, then $\chi \models \psi$.

Finally, they build an injective function from $2^{\omega}$ to $\mathcal{S}_n^\mathcal{M}$ by assigning some $p \in \bigcap\limits_{n < \omega} [\varphi(f \restriction n)]$ for all $f : \omega \rightarrow 2$.
It is clear to me why this would be one-to-one if it were well-defined, but I don't understand why $\bigcap\limits_{n < \omega} [\varphi(f \restriction n)]$ is non-empty.

If you don't understand the proof in Marker's book, what makes you think you'll understand a proof that someone writes here? To get a  helpful answer, you should at the very least tell us what parts of Marker's proof you're having trouble with.

Also: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

@AlexKruckman It is unclear to me why the intersection of all [psi] of formulas that occur in a particular path is non-empty.

Great, that's a precise question! So to make this a good, self-contained question that meets the the standards of this site, you should edit your question, write out enough of the details of the proof that you do understand up to the point you got stuck so that people without the book at hand can understand the question), and then ask why the paths are consistent.

@AlexKruckman Should be better now.

@TodorDukov it’s a decreasing sequence of nonempty closed subsets of a compact space.

For the record: the original version of this question did not meet quality standards, but with my advice, the OP edited it and turned it into a good question. It should not have been closed.

"By compactness."
In his book, Marker gives an explanation using topological compactness:

Because $[\phi_{f|0}]\supseteq [\phi_{f|1}]\supseteq [\phi_{f|2}]\supseteq \dots$ and $S^{\mathcal{M}}_n(A)$ is compact, there is $p_f\in \bigcap_{n=0}^\infty [\phi_{f|n}]$.

(Here I've corrected two typos in the book: Marker wrote $\bigcup$ instead of $\bigcap$, and he is inconsistent about whether to write $\varphi_{f|n}$ or $\varphi(f|n)$.)
Do you know that in a compact space $X$, any descending chain of non-empty closed sets has non-empty intersection? The reason is that if $C_0\supseteq C_1\subseteq C_2\supseteq\dots$ and $\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty C_n = \varnothing$, then $\{X\setminus C_n\mid n\in \omega\}$ is an open cover of $X$. By compactness, there is some $N$ such that $\{X\setminus C_n\mid n\leq N\}$ is an open cover of $X$. But then $C_N = \bigcap_{n=0}^N C_n = \varnothing$, contradicting the hypothesis that each $C_n$ is non-empty.

We can also phrase this argument in the language of model-theoretic compactness.
I claim that the partial type $\Phi = \{\varphi_{f|n}\mid n\in \omega\}$ is consistent. A finite subset of $\Phi$ is contained in $\Phi_N = \{\varphi_{f|n}\mid n\leq N\}$ for some $N\in \omega$, and $\Phi_N$ is equivalent to $\phi_{f|N}$, which is consistent by hypothesis. By the compactness theorem, $\Phi$ is consistent. Pick some element $a$ (in an elementary extension of $\mathcal{M}$) realizing $\Phi$, and let $p_f = \mathrm{tp}(a/A)$.
